# Can't Link a List to a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

So I have a simple combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list_match}"/>
```

As you can see, that combobox binds to "list_match"; which I create in my code:

```
public List<string> list_match = new List<string>();
```

At some point in my code, I execute the following call:

```
load_combo(list_match);
```

This line sends the list to a function:

```
public void load_combo(List<string> list)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("combo.txt"))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            list.Add(line);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am always getting an empty combobox and the list is not binding to the combobox. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `DataContext` is set accordingly you should use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, if you want to see changes to a collection reflected in the UI and you [cannot bind to fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx) so `list_match` should be a public property

```
public ObservableCollection<string> list_match { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

Lets say you have `MyWindow` window which contains your `ComboBox`

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _list_match = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> list_match { get { return _list_match; } }

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed all instances to `List` to `ObservableCollection`, as well as set `this.DataContext = this;`... still not working

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Make sure list_match is a property, not a field.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod and it's now a property as well? If yes then where do you create `list_match`? Is it in constructor before `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: I dont understand... I have `public ObservableCollection<string> list_match = new ObservableCollection<string>();`

Comment: It must be a property, not a field. You need `{ get; set; }`. Field is not a valid binding source and if you don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `list_match` then it's important when you create your class. Best place to do that, in such case, is constructor before `InitializeComponent`

Comment: Hmm... removing the assignment of the ItemsSource from the XAML and putting it in code `combobox.ItemsSource = list_match` fixed it completely... without everything else...

Comment: Yes, because it does not use binding anymore. You can set `ItemSource` manually to any `IEnumarable` and it should work but if you want to use bindings, which you should do, then it must be public property in correct binding context

Comment: @JasonAxelrod check my update if you want to make it work for binding

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Do you mind going into why I would want to use bindings instead of just assigning the ItemsSource in the code? Assigning in code seems to work perfectly, and its far less lines.

Comment: Now it may seem easier to access control by name in code but when it's part of some template it won't so easy and when you work with more complicated controls like DataGrid and more complicated layouts it's much easier to use binding. When you follow MVVM pattern, and use bindings technically all you need to do is set DataContext to your view model then UI should create itself without your intervention. It gives you this separation of UI and your view model class